# getting NoSuchMethodError for getNamespaceContext() when running with jdk 1.5 but not with 1.6

Tags: java, jax-ws, java-5, nosuchmethoderror

I'm running a program written in java, deployed on an Oracle application Server, running 1.5 JVM.following is the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.getNamespaceContext()Lcom/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/xni/NamespaceContext;
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.<init>(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:99)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.getXMLStreamReaderImpl(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:264)
 at com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl.createXMLStreamReader(XMLInputFactoryImpl.java:136)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory$Zephyr.newInstance(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:251)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.api.streaming.XMLStreamReaderFactory.<clinit>(XMLStreamReaderFactory.java:84)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:805)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:262)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:129)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:265)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:228)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:176)
 at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
 at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
 at com.earthport.bind.MerchantAPIService.<init>(MerchantAPIService.java:50)
 at com.earthport.client.service.stub.MerchantAPIClientImpl$1CustomMerchantAPIService.    <init>(MerchantAPIClientImpl.java:107)
 at     com.earthport.client.service.stub.MerchantAPIClientImpl.createMerchantAPIService(MerchantAPI    ClientImpl.java:111)
 at com.earthport.client.service.stub.MerchantAPIClientImpl.<init>    (MerchantAPIClientImpl.java:84)
 at     com.earthport.client.service.ServiceProxyFactoryImpl.createServiceProxy(ServiceProxyFactoryI    mpl.java:25)
 at utils.AmxEPAccCre.<init>(AmxEPAccCre.java:79)
 at utils.WService.<init>(WService.java:95)
 at utils.WService.main(WService.java:795)
Process exited.
```

If i run the exact same program with jdk 1.6 though, the program runs perfectly. Is this a specific issue with a library reference? anyone see this exception before?

cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are having a conflict between the Xerces implementation that comes with your app or the Oracle AppServer, and the one that comes with the JDK.

It works with the one that comes in JDK6, but is not compatible with the one in JDK 5.